# Kusto summarize where between?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a series of logs, which I group based on certain steps that occur (based on data in the line)

One step could potentially be repeated multiple times after the official end of the sequence (step 4), I would like to reject those from the summarize statement.

In the table below, the first group should be between lines 1 and 6, the second group should be between lines 9 and 14. I would summarize these by group, but I want to reject the records that occur after step 4 for each sequence.

example data

| Line | timestamp | step | group | LogLine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000-07-01T16:51 | 1 | 1 | init |
| 2 | 2000-07-01T16:52 | 2 | 1 | start |
| 3 | 2000-07-01T16:53 | 3 | 1 | 20% |
| 4 | 2000-07-01T16:53 | 3 | 1 | 21% |
| 5 | 2000-07-01T16:53 | 3 | 1 | 23% |
| 6 | 2000-07-01T16:54 | 4 | 1 | end |
| 7 | 2000-07-01T16:55 | 3 | 1 | 19% |
| 8 | 2000-07-01T16:56 | 3 | 1 | 18% |
| 9 | 2000-07-01T16:57 | 1 | 2 | init |
| 10 | 2000-07-01T16:58 | 2 | 2 | start |
| 11 | 2000-07-01T16:59 | 3 | 2 | 45% |
| 12 | 2000-07-01T17:00 | 3 | 2 | 47% |
| 13 | 2000-07-01T17:01 | 3 | 2 | 52% |
| 14 | 2000-07-01T17:02 | 4 | 2 | end |
| 15 | 2000-07-01T17:01 | 3 | 2 | 51% |
| 16 | 2000-07-01T17:02 | 3 | 2 | 48% |
| 17 | 2000-07-01T17:01 | 3 | 2 | 46% |
| 18 | 2000-07-01T17:02 | 3 | 2 | 43% |
| 19 | 2000-07-01T17:01 | 3 | 2 | 42% |
| 20 | 2000-07-01T17:02 | 3 | 2 | 41% |

Essentially im trying to do a

```
summarize .........
by group where timestamp between (step1Timestamp, step4Timestamp)
```

Is this possible?

What I expect after the summarize (which I know how to do). I just dont know how to limit the results of step 3 between the timestamps of steps 1 and 4.

| group | start% | end% | startTime | endTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20% | 23% | 2000-07-01T16:51 | 2000-07-01T16:54 |
| 2 | 45% | 52% | 2000-07-01T16:57 | 2000-07-01T17:02 |

Note that I cannot use min/max for the percentages in step 3, as it would give me values that occur after step 4 for some groupings.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is an awesome operator for this already! Thanks to one of my co-workers for pointing this out.

`scan` Operator

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator

```
| scan with_match_id=m_id with 
(
    step s1: step== "1";
    step s2: step!= "4" and  timestamp - s1.timestamp <= 5m;
    step s3: step== "4"  and timestamp - s1.timestamp <= 5m;
)
```

Comment: A note (for others who're reading this): the `scan` operator is only available with EngineV3. If you're running EngineV2, you can open a support ticket and we'll migrate your cluster. (We're in the process of migrating all clusters from V2 to V3 anyway)